# Prepared Statements With MySQL in .Net @ VS.?

Tags: .net, mysql, prepared-statement

According to the [MySQL .Net connector docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-using-prepared.html), when running prepared statements, the @ symbol is used to defined a paramter.  When trying this I got an error.  Then the user comment at the bottom of the page says if you have problems, substitute the ? for the @ character.  Is there any way to control what character MySQL expects for prepared statements?  I would prefer that it used to the "@" symbol as it would make it more similar to SQL Server, which I'm trying to migrate from.

Comment: What is the error? Can you post some code ?

Comment: There is no error if I use the ? character as the first character of my parameters.  This is fine, everything works.  Except that I would rather use the @ character as shown in the docs, and which is the same character used by SQL Server.

Comment: What version of the MySQL Connector are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Old Syntax, OldSyntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlconnection-connectionstring): Allows use
>   of '@' symbol as a parameter marker.
>   This option was deprecated in
>   Connector/NET 5.2.2. All future code
>   should be written using the '@'
>   symbol.

```
MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection();
myConnection.ConnectionString = "**OldSyntax=true**; server=myHost; database=myDB; Username=myUser; pwd=myPass; ";
myConnection.Open();
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Perhaps an error in the MySQL Documentation, that second "@" symbol should probably be "?".

Comment: according to http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37349, "starting with 5.2 you should be using '@' but '?' will still work". also: "'@' is *again* the recommended identifier" ...).

which version are you using? 5.2.x?

Comment: I'm using 5.2.5.  Just downloaded it a week ago. I'm confused though, what's the proper syntax supposed to be now?